# Failed to connect (BinetMenuItem) outlet from (NSCustomObject) to (NSMenuItem): missing setter or instance variable

Tags: objective-c, macos

I recompiled some previously working code after updating to **Xcode 6.3 and OS X 10.10.3** and got the error above.  I have declared a @property named BinetMenuItem and have used @synthesize (which I thought creates getters and setters). Here is the relevant code, first from the header file:

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> {
   // lots of stuff that's not relevant (I hope)
}
  @property (assign) IBOutlet NSMenuItem *BinetMenuItem;
  @property (assign) IBOutlet NSMenuItem *PoinsotMenuItem;
  @property (assign) IBOutlet NSMenuItem *polhodeMenuItem;
  @property (assign) IBOutlet NSMenuItem *toggleMovieMenuItem;

- (IBAction)setBinetMode:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)setPoinsotMode:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)setPolhodeMode:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)toggleMovie:(id)sender;
```

**and now from the .m file:**

```
@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize BinetMenuItem;
@synthesize PoinsotMenuItem;
@synthesize polhodeMenuItem;
@synthesize toggleMovieMenuItem;

- (IBAction)setBinetMode:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"%s starting BinetMode", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    if (animationMode == PoinsotMode | animationMode == polhodeMode) {
        NSLog(@"Setting initial conditions");
        animationMode = BinetMode;
        [self setInitialConditions:self];
    }
    animationMode = BinetMode;
    [bodyOnlyMenuItem setState:NSOffState];
    [BinetMenuItem setState:NSOnState];
    [PoinsotMenuItem setState:NSOffState];
    [polhodeMenuItem setState:NSOffState];
    [view setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}

@end
```

The app uses nibs, not storyboards.  Is there any other information that might help?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found it!  It had nothing to do with the code I posted: I had added this -init method:

```
-(id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        topLevelObjects = [[NSMutableArray array] retain];
    }
}
```

Note the lack of a return value. When I added "return self;" as the line after "topLevelObjects = ..." and "return nil;" just after the first close bracket, everything worked fine.  Note to self: pay attention to warnings.  Compiling under 10.10.3 produced a number of deprecation warnings, and I didn't look through for any others.  Sloppy...